# How to make static blocks in muuri grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, draggable, muuri

I have a grid with more than 5 items and all items are inside grid class. Now i want to make 2 of these block static / non draggable. How can i achieve this ?

I have tried the following code but its not working for me.

```
var staticBlock = document.querySelector('.static-block');
var staticItem = grid.getItems([staticBlock])[0];

// Override the drag handle to prevent dragging
staticItem.getElement().addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent dragging when clicked
});
```